# iOS - Payment issue using Paypal iOS SDK

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk, payment

I've used Paypal iOS SDK for Payment purpose, since a week I've been facing a problem with payment process. Getting an error like

> "Declined by Fraud Service: 11611-Transaction blocked by your settings
>   in FMF".

Since a year it had been working fine and I haven't changed anything from its integration part but recently (suddenly) I'm getting an error. Is there any update required with settings of iOS SDK?
I tried to look around this link (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/fmf/integration-guide/FMFIntro/) but could not find exact solution for mobile app. Pl. help if any one is aware about this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this question. There is no technical solution of this problem. Question has an answer to a question. Reason for this error is [Activation of Fraud Management Filters](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/fmf/integration-guide/FMFIntro/). Fraud Management Filters (FMF)  filters fraudulent transactions.

Following sample possible reasons provided by Paypal for such error:

- Country Monitor filter, which identifies transactions based on the
  country of origin
- Card Security Code Mismatch filter, which identifies transactions with differences in the credit card security code. (When a customer tries to checkout using an incorrect/mismatch billing address, cvv or expired date registered with the card.)
- Maximum Transaction Amount filter, which identifies transactions whose value exceeds a specified amount
- Total Purchase Price Minimum filter, which identifies transactions that are less than a specified amount

> In my case actual issue and reason for this error was: Customer had
>   provided wrong/incorrect information about payment card, which was
>   filtered by Paypal as fraudulent activity. And rejected transaction
>   for that customer.

I solved this problem by informing customer to register this information in its account and verify the same to Paypal.